# Want to create a dynamic page to list content by letter

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to create a dynamic page in WP theme so that when I pass a letter from 'A-Z' it will display all the posts with the title starting from that letter.
Can you please tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using themes and getting the index key via a query parameter then you can create a new custom theme file and add the following code to get the list of posts.

```
$thePostIdArray = null;
    $indexkey = $_GET['indexkey']; 
    if ($indexkey!=null){
        $querystr = "
            SELECT wposts.ID 
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
            WHERE UPPER(wposts.post_title) like '".$indexkey."%' 
            AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
            ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
         ";
        $thePostArray = $wpdb->get_results($querystr); 
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($thePostArray as $currentPost){
            $thePostIdArray[$i] = $currentPost->ID;
            $i++;
        }
```

After that just just a matter of going through the post array and displaying them.